# Floating 4 input boxes equally with background color

Tags: html, css

I am trying to float 4 boxes along the full width of my webpage with equal spacing between them.

Currently the output looks as follows:
[image: Display now]

This was achieved with the following HTML and CSS

```css
.info {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 20px 20px 40px 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
}

.go_button {
  width: 175px;
  background-color: #01C3A7;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 0.429rem;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: Circular, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.429rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  padding: 3px;
}

.box {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <div class="box_container">
    <div class="box">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Departure Station" id="depart">
      <input type="hidden" id="departID" name="DeptStationID" style="display: none">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Arrival Station" id="arrive">
      <input type="hidden" id="arriveID" name="ArrvStationID" style="display: none">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <input type="text" id="datepicker" value="@DateTime.Now.Date.ToString(" yyyy/MM/dd ")" name="DeptDate">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <input type="text" id="timepicker" name="time">
    </div>
    <div class="box"><button type="submit" name="Submit" class="go_button">Go</button></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The output I am trying to require is as follows:
[image: What i want]

I want this to be able to resize according to the screen display and therefore cannot set a margin using pixels. Currently when i do resize the output, it produces the following:

[image: background color not filled]

As you can see, the background color does not fill all four boxes. I have added height:auto and this does not fix the issue.

Please can you let me know how to fix these issues.

Answer (score 2):

I would use flexbox with `justify-content:space-between` rather than floats

```css
.info {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 20px 20px 40px 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
}

.go_button {
  width: 175px;
  background-color: #01C3A7;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 0.429rem;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: Circular, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.429rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  padding: 3px;
}

.box_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <div class="box_container">
    <div class="box">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Departure Station" id="depart">
      <input type="hidden" id="departID" name="DeptStationID" style="display: none">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Arrival Station" id="arrive">
      <input type="hidden" id="arriveID" name="ArrvStationID" style="display: none">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <input type="text" id="datepicker" value="@DateTime.Now.Date.ToString(" yyyy/MM/dd ")" name="DeptDate">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <input type="text" id="timepicker" name="time">
    </div>
    <div class="box"><button type="submit" name="Submit" class="go_button">Go</button></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use flex box.

try something out like the following:

**FIDDLE**

https://jsfiddle.net/pcehxx7f/16/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  display: flex;  
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.box { 
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.box input { 
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the next hack...

```
.box_container:after{
  content:'';
  display:block;
  clear:both;
}
```

This adds a last element in your container, using the [clear property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp), this is happening because the float element don't take space in its container..

```css
.info {
    background-color: black;
    padding: 20px 20px 40px 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
}
.go_button {
    width: 175px;
    background-color: #01C3A7;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 0.429rem;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Circular,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.429rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    padding: 3px;
}
.box {
    float: left;
}
.box_container:after{
  content:'';
  display:block;
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
    <div class="box_container">
        <div class="box">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Departure Station" id="depart">
            <input type="hidden" id="departID" name="DeptStationID" style="display: none">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Arrival Station" id="arrive">
            <input type="hidden" id="arriveID" name="ArrvStationID" style="display: none">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <input type="text" id="datepicker" value="@DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")" name="DeptDate">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <input type="text" id="timepicker" name="time">
        </div>
        <div class="box"><button type="submit" name="Submit" class="go_button">Go</button></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This only clears the floats, it doesn't answer OPs problem of *I am trying to float 4 boxes along the **full width of my webpage with equal spacing between them***

Answer (score 0):

Use [Clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) to automatically close elemts float.

How it works is well described in this question: 
[What is a clearfix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-a-clearfix#8554054)

But much better solution is to use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox). 
Nice flexbox guide can be found on [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)